# Discord bot can not read content of the message

Tags: python, discord.py

HI I want to make a bot on discord. I can make a bot with see that message is coming. But it can not see a content of the message.

my code:

```
import discord
import os
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("This is user {0.user}".format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(message)
  print(message.content)
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("$hello"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello!")

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN3']

client.run(my_secret)
```

my output:
<Message id=1089613042033111062 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=1029808272267550740 name='l_programmer' discriminator='1926' bot=False nick=None guild=> flags=>

[image: my URL settings]
[image: my bot settings]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the message content intent in your bot itself.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```